# How to create a Menubar application for Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, menubar

EDIT: This is a nice ready-made menubar application [here](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html) ([github source](https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup)) by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6834833/264795).

---

I was wondering how to make a menubar application, what are the requirements for that to do so?

I saw a simple application for the menubar was to open links using your browser, I want to create something similar to that.

[image]

This is the application I like to make similar.

Comment: Here is a simple [tutorial](http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/creating-a-os-x-menubar-only-app/).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

[NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem?language=objc) is what you are looking for. Also add LSUIElement with string value of 1 to your Info.plist to hide it from Dock.

Comment: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.22/22.02/Menulet/ - here's a sample code with some explanation.

Comment: You can check out one of my GitHug projects for an example: https://github.com/nippysaurus/WeatherRock/blob/master/BrissyBomAppDelegate.m#L59

Comment: I implemented the example described in SteamTrout's link and put it on github. It is here: https://github.com/wanderingstan/IPMenuletExample

Comment: Hello Steam Trout, thanks for your help... but how can we keep our application shortcut always in menu bar, until user uninstall the application... any help.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605687/keep-application-shortcut-always-in-system-menubar-application-for-mac

Answer (score 67):

I've found [Codebox's Popup](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html) to be a great starting point.  It is ripe for [forking on Github.](https://github.com/shpakovski/Popup)

[image]

Though it works nicely, they do note on their site...

> P. S. In Lion, Apple is adding a new class for popovers like in iOS.
>   So, after OS X 10.7 is released, you would better to rely on native
>   Cocoa classes where it is possible. In other cases, the Popup project
>   should still be usable.

Comment: This is not true in any case. NSPopover has serious limitations: Text Fields/Views cannot become first responder and thus you cannot enter text.

Comment: @ChristianKienle so would you still recommend to starting out with the Popup application with OS X versions > 10.7?

Comment: Yes. NSPopover + Status Item have serious limitations in 10.7 and 10.8. For example the screenshot above shows a search field. By using a NSPopover you cannot interact with the search field properly.

Comment: why does Codebox's Popup sample have such a complicated BackgroundPanel?

Answer (score 16):

[BitBar](https://getbitbar.com/) is an application on [GitHub](https://github.com/matryer/bitbar) that can "Put anything in your Mac OS X menu bar".

It runs shell or other executable scripts (which it calls [Plugins - see the many examples in the plugins repo](https://github.com/matryer/bitbar-plugins)) and displays the results in the menu bar. You can write your own plugin and have it run simply by adding it to the 'Plugins folder'. As well as displaying information, it can also run pre-defined bash scripts interactively from the plugin menus you define.

Since I first posted this answer it's popularity has [exploded](https://medium.com/@matryer/what-happens-when-your-old-open-source-project-unexpectedly-gets-to-the-top-of-hacker-news-31114c6c6efb#.su9apjr4q) (52 contributors currently) and there is now even a distributable version with which you can package your own plugins.

A very simple (non-interactive) example to show live Bitcoin price:

[image]

Comment: thanks to [cwd](http://stackoverflow.com/users/288032/cwd) for improving my rather poor original answer

Answer (score 11):

As Apple added `NSStatusBarButton` property to `NSStatusItem` in Yosemite, we can implement menubar app a lot simpler. I just created a sample project on github.

https://github.com/taichino/PopupTest

Comment: Thank you for putting this together!

Answer (score 3):

[FlyCut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut) is another nice open source application that does this. (MIT licensed.) Very handy too, I use it several times a day.

Here's some code that seems like it may be relevant:

```
    // Flycut/AppController.h
    IBOutlet NSMenu *jcMenu;

    // Flycut/AppController.m
    statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]
            statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    if ( [[DBUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"menuIcon"] == 1 ) {
        [statusItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",0x2704]]; 
    } else if ( [[DBUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"menuIcon"] == 2 ) {
        [statusItem setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",0x2702]]; 
    } else {
        [statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"com.generalarcade.flycut.16.png"]];
    }
    [statusItem setMenu:jcMenu];
    [statusItem setEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: Hi funroll, i would like to keep this shortcut always in menu bar like default valume control in mac is it possible with programming... please help me!!!

Comment: @VSN StackOverflow comments aren't a good place to ask for help like this. I would suggest reading [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i have asked new question- any help there .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23605687/keep-application-shortcut-always-in-system-menubar-application-for-mac

Answer (score 1):

[Mail Notifr](http://ashchan.com/projects/gmail-notifr) is another open source Menubar app. It helped me a bunch, especially when I needed to figure out how to implement the open on login. Also available on the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/gmail-notifr/id808154494?ls=1&mt=12).