# How can I make a Mac application having an icon only in the menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, statusbar, menubar

I'm very new to developing for the Mac, and I'm trying to write a Cocoa application whose only presence is in the system menu bar, and does not appear in the Dock. Dropbox, Alfred, and Quicksilver do this (or can be configured to do this). Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Menubar application for Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)