# How can I show a menubar icon in Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, menubar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Menubar application for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)

I want to show an icon in mac's top menu bar.
In the Interface Builder, there's no item about that.
Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [NSStatusBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).