# Custom NSMenu item

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how can i go about making a custom NSMenu for a menulet such as this?

Is this an NSMenu or is it a borderless window and if so how would i go about this?
Thanks!

[image: http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/049/Purple/b1/33/08/mzl.bmiomoxu.800x500-75.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an app running running on the OSX status bar.

See [Status Bar Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i) at Apple. Also, [NSStatusBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000247) and [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000248)

This SO post has some additional pointers:

[How to create a Menubar application for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)

Answer (score 1):

More specifically it could be an `NSPopover`, an `NSWindow`, or even `NSStatusItem.view`'s custom view. In the case of an `NSWindow` (often a utility form of `NSPanel`) (or the `NSPopover`) you would manually open the window when the status item is clicked, using the status item's `-(void)setAction` and `-(void)setTarget`. If you use a custom view for the status item, this would be done in `-mouseDown:`.

Check out [this](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html) post - I found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for `NSStatusItem`. I believe you can have it display a view instead of a standard `NSMenu` which is what it looks like they are doing in that image.