# Mac OS X Lion Menu Bar Application

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Menubar application for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)

I am looking to being creating an OS X Menu Bar App in Lion, and I was wondering how I would go about starting. I can't find any places on the internet and there is no default option in the create new project. The app I want to make, I would prefer be only a menu bar app, no actual app that launches with any windows. If there are any good places to learn how to make one somewhere else, please let me know. Thanks for the help

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239399/mac-menu-bar-tutorial, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270515/custom-nsmenu-item, this question has been asked a lot, and it hasn't changed much in Lion with the exception of the addition of NSPopover.

Comment: I have a simple tutorial [here](http://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/10/10/creating-a-os-x-menubar-only-app/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create an `NSStatusItem`.

[*Status Bar Programming Topics*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/StatusBar/StatusBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000073i)
[*NSStatusItem Class Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000248)

Answer (score 7):

A "menubar app" is simply a normal application with the NSUIElement flag turned on. It'll be easier to work on your application without that flag set, so just start out with a normal application.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I never knew that!