# Simple Mac OS development app

Tags: macos, menubar

What is the app's icon that appears to the right of the menu bar called?(like the twitter one)

When you press it, it's usually a drop down menu..

I want to implement a similar one in my mac app.. any help where can i start?

[image: How can i make a similar icon for my app?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu icon is a status item, represented by the [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. See the question [How to create a menubar application for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac) and its answers for more info.