# Sync iOS & Mac OS X data

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

Friends I am working on an app with two versions i.e. iOS & Mac OS X. Currently I am exploring my options to sync core data of iOS version to Mac OS X and vice versa.

Could someone suggest me regarding right tools/apis for the same. Or someone have some tips on how to do the same.

The only condition is we can't use cloud/webservice based syncing.

--- Update 01 ---

While working towards the solution, I explored towards syncing via HTTPServer inline/embeded in an app.
http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/simple-extensible-http-server-in-cocoa.html

This allows iOS app to share data but via its IP. I am confused how an OS X app would be able to detect the IP or is there any iPhone connected with the Mac OS.

Just to clarify what I am exactly looking for is ---

User work on any one of the app iOS app OR Mac OSx app. Then user connect the iPhone with Mac machine and sync the data.

I hope someone would be able to guide me accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to create a [Status Menu Bar Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac) on Mac and sync your data with [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/).

The syncing itself is not so easy (if it's directly iOS<->Mac or not iOS<->Cloud<-Mac/iOS->). You might start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035132/how-to-sync-iphone-core-data-with-web-server-and-then-push-to-other-devices).

Comment: Could you please provide any examples/tutorials/refs for libimobiledevice, as the same looks a lot complicated to me.