# Menu status applications doubts

Tags: objective-c, osx-mountain-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Menubar application for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)

I have implemented a feed with Cocoa, for Mac OS X.
It's a status application, displaying only the menu.Now basically I got three questions:

- When I launch it I always see the application icon in the dock.But this is a menu status application, how do I remove the dock icon? It should be an application like Watts and Dropbox, a pure menu;
- How do I prevent the user from launching the application multiple times? If the user does so, I would like to not launch a second instance of the application.

Comment: You are asking two different questions, which requires two different answer.

Comment: I understand that this was a double question, I removed the third point and removed the iOS and iPhone tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I prevent the user from launching the application multiple
>   times? If the user does so, I would like to not launch a second
>   instance of the application.

That would commonly be done using a filesystem lock (`flock`) on unix based systems.

But then again, Cocoa has an even simpler solution for that; you may check if an application is active by supplying its bundle identifier to the system.

```
NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:
```

See the [NSRunningApplication Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more.

Comment: Actually, for number two, I recommend an NSMachPort check: https://gist.github.com/3956491