# Modifying screen bounds in osx programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

I have an application that replaces the original osx desktop. I need to implement an information bar in my desktop replacement so that it would always be visible (kinda like the mac menu bar). So i was wondering...

- is there a way to somehow move mac's menu bar down maybe like 20 pixels?
- is there a way to somehow move mac's dock up a few pixels?

That way i could just implement the information at the top or bottom of the desktop. I don't think it's possible though, but if anyone knows of any solution (either applescript or some app or **preferably objective-c**, i'd very much love to hear about it.

Thanks

Comment: So your app is going to go over the desktop? Why not just hide the doc and then have your app take up the whole screen? Or make the app start in fullscreen mode?

Comment: @Josh the main idea is to have an app that can display information that would always be visible to me no matter what app i'm using at the moment (just like dock and menubar are always visible). Basically what i want is an additional toolbar-like app that other application windows could never cover. I hope this clears things a bit.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way to move the Dock or menu bar. But could you just make your application a floating window that stays in the front at all times? That's very easy to do in Cocoa with a line like:

`myWindow.level = NSFloatingWindowLevel;`

(Assuming you have an `NSWindow *` called `myWindow` already created.)

Instead of moving the other UI elements, could you just anchor that window to the left or right side of the screen? (Assuming your Dock is on the bottom -- although note that if you are distributing the app to others, it might not always be... mine is on the left, for example.)

Maybe I'm missing something about what you want to do, but to me it seems a bit easier to anchor your own info bar somewhere else, rather than try to move around the core Mac UI elements.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the answer. However, if i anchor my bar anywhere, the  other application interfaces would still be able to be moved behind that bar. And that would interfere with the functionality of those other apps. I don't just want to anchor my bar somewhere, but to also make that area unavailable for any other application (like you can't move anything behind the menu bar or resize anything behind the dock) so that my bar would never be on top of any application window. But i don't think this is possible.

Comment: @Marius Yeah, I'm not sure of the exact way you might go about solving that problem. I'm relatively new to Cocoa dev myself so I don't have tons of answers, but I do know that the `-visibleFrame` method of `NSScreen` returns the usable area of the screen, minus the Dock area and menu bar. I'm assuming that this is what the system uses to prevent other windows and such from going into those areas? If that's correct, you could potentially look into 'swizzling' the `-visibleFrame` method. I'm just starting to read into that myself, but maybe it would work? Or maybe that's too much trouble...

Comment: yeah i've read about it as well prior to comming to this forum ;] Unfortunately, you can only read the active area of the screen, but not set it :(

Comment: That's why I suggested 'swizzling' the method. Which means you replace the OS's built-in method with one you wrote. So your code can jump in when other applications call `-visibleFrame` and return a slightly smaller rectangle than the OS would return. Swizzling system methods is not generally considered great practice if you can avoid it, as it can lead to lots of bugs and unexpected behavior if you don't do it exactly right... but if you're trying to modify the system's behavior for other applications, sometimes it's the only way, and it can be OK when used responsibly and minimally.

Comment: Check out the SIMBL framework if you want to look into that more. I haven't used it myself as I haven't had a strong need to do any such swizzling yet, but it's what everyone seems to recommend if you are trying to do stuff like this. Keeps you from having to reinvent the wheel, and makes it easier to pull off a swizzle successfully -- it's kind of tricky to get right, but I'm told SIMBL takes care of some of the harder parts for you.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. I'll definitely have a look at the swizzling approach. But would a simple method swap really affect other apps, instead of just mine?

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking of is something like a `modal window` that will always stay frontmost (until its dealt with). However, modal windows (like a password prompt) are obnoxious, and probably not what you're looking for.

If you want a "Menu Bar like" application, why reinvent the wheel? Why not just make a **[Menu Bar Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac)**. Menu Bar Apps run in the menu bar, and can display information up there, like your clock, battery percentage, cpu usage, wifi, etc. and seem to be exactly what you need. When clicked they can offer the user a myriad of options and more information in their dropdown.

Comment: Josh, i don't need to reinvent a wheel, because i don't need a menubar application. My app would display loads of information and there's not enough free space in the menu bar to do so. And i need the info to be displayed all at once, without any scrolling or anything. Modal windows are also not what i'm looking for, unfortunately. Even [NSWindow setLevel] is not ok for this purpose.