# How can you build an app and add it to the menu in OSX?

Tags: macos

I have experience with iOS but I'm not sure where to start with OSX

I want to build an app that is just a menu in the "finder/main" bar like dropbox for example?

What type of app is that in Xcode?

Comment: I think this is what you mean... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409985/how-to-create-a-menubar-application-for-mac

Comment: oh yes let me read it! thank you

Comment: how can I accept your answer @MarkSetchell

Comment: You can't - it is only a comment. I didn't think it was worthy as a point-earning answer as it is only a link to someone else's work. But thanks anyway and good luck building your app.